# Python: select column from table with delimiter "\"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a script, after running it I get the result:

```html
['\r', '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6079\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate\r', '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6082\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate\r', '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6084\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate\r', '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6087\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate']
['\r', 'CREATE_TS\tRULE_CD\tPACKAGE_CD\tRULE_STTS\r', '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_4662\tPKL_PACKOUT_VD_543_T_ERTYU_SCORE\tWait']
```

I used iloc but I get the error: single positional indexer is out of bounds

```html
i = pd.dataframe(list(i))
i = i.iloc[:,1]
```

myscript:

```html
task_list = []
for i in task_list:
    i = i[4]
    i = i.split('\n')[1:]
    print(i)
```

I am confused and cannot select a column with data

```html
PKL_PACKOUT_RP_069
PKL_PACKOUT_RP_069
PKL_PACKOUT_RP_069
PKL_PACKOUT_RP_069

PKL_PACKOUT_VD_543_T_ERTYU_SCORE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = ['\r', '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6079\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate\r',
      '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6082\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate\r',
      '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6084\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate\r',
      '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_6087\tPKL_PACKOUT_RP_069\tFinish_terminate',
      '\r', 'CREATE_TS\tRULE_CD\tPACKAGE_CD\tRULE_STTS\r',
      '30-APR-21\tRTYKD_4662\tPKL_PACKOUT_VD_543_T_ERTYU_SCORE\tWait']
i = pd.DataFrame(i)
i = i.iloc[:,0]
task_list = []
for n in range(len(i)):
    n = i[n]
    n = n.split('\t')
    print(n)
```

your dataframe have one column and its location is 0 in this case,i made some changes in the code but you use task_list where u use this variable?cause its empty list and you iterate over this list